# Lie bracket on submanifolds

Tags: smooth-manifolds, vector-fields

> Suppose we have a smooth manifold $M$ and an embedded/immersed submanifold $N \subset M$.

As usual, for every $p \in N$, we identify $T_pN$ as $(di)_p(T_pN)$, where $i:N \hookrightarrow M$ is the inclusion.

Now let's say that we have two smooth vector fields $X$ and $Y$ on $M$ which happen to be tangent to $N$ (i.e. $X_p, Y_p \in T_pN, \forall p \in N$).

We know that in this case, the Lie bracket of $X$ and $Y$ in $M$, call it $[X,Y]_M$ is also tangent to $N$.

However, what about their Lie bracket on $N$? By this I mean, taking the restrictions $X^*$ and $Y^*$ of these vector fields to $N$ (i.e. two smooth vector fields $X^*, Y^*$ on $N$ which are $i$-related with $X$ and $Y$, respectively), how would we compute the Lie bracket of $[X^*, Y^*]_N$ in $N$?

It seems "trivial" that
$$
[X^*, Y^*]_N = \left. [X, Y]_M \right|_{TN}.
$$
However, how would we go about proving this? I don't really know how to start, as it seems just too trivial.

**Context:** I firstly thought about this when I encountered the vector fields
$$ 
X_1 = z\partial_y - y\partial_z, X_2 = x\partial_z - z\partial_x, X_3 = y\partial_x - x\partial_y,
$$
which are smooth vector fields on $\mathbb{R}^3$ but also "happen" to be tangent to the sphere $S^2$.
I then wanted to compute the Lie bracket $[X_1, X_2]$ **on $S^2$**. I just computed it in the classical way in $\mathbb{R}^3$, and then restricted it to $S^2$.

Comment: The key tool to describe this phenomenon is the notion of an $F$-related vector field. Given a smooth map $F:M\to N$, a we say a vector field $X\in\mathfrak{X}M$ is *$F$-related to* $Y\in\mathfrak{X}N$ if $d_pX_p=Y_{F(p)}$ for all $p\in M$. The relevant theorem is that if $X,Y$ are $F$-related to $X',Y'$ respectively, then $[X,Y]$ is $F$-related to $[X',Y']$. [This question](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2528110/the-commutators-of-related-vector-fields-are-related) discusses a proof of this theorem.

Comment: Indeed it does: we can apply it to the inclusion $i$, which yields $(di)_p([X^*, Y^*]_p) = [X, Y]_p$, so, when identifying $TN$ as $di(TN)$, we get indeed that $[X^*, Y^*] = [X, Y]|_{TN}$. Thank you!